# Assembly.Load + AppDomain.CreateDomain

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, appdomainsetup

I'm loading new assembly (`CLRHostHelper.dll`) using `Assembly.Load( byte[] )` method. From that assembly I'm calling `AppDomain.CreateDomain` - method throws exception:

`Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'CLRHostHelper, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

To my best understanding new appDomain creation can only proceed only if there physically exists .dll on disk (Using `AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup() { ApplicationBase = inDir };` it's possible to specify from which folder) - and it's not possible to load it in ram only.

It's possible to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += newapp_AssemblyResolve;` - but that event is applicable only to current appDomain, not to newly created.

It's also not possible to immediately hook AssemblyResolve of new appDomain - there is no such method.

In class AppDomainSetup - there exists also AppDomainManagerAssembly and AppDomainManagerType - more info can be found from here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/11/12/the-managed-hosting-api/
In theory we could create our own AppDomainManager, and override EntryAssembly to provide our own assembly, but:

```
domainSetup.AppDomainManagerAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
domainSetup.AppDomainManagerType = "EchoAppDomainManager";
```

Here you again specify assembly name, which in a turn needs to be loaded from disk.

In here - http://andrewzak.tumblr.com/ - `Small .NET desktop applications. Turning on shadow copying.` there is some mentions about similar problem, and potential walk around using `SetAppDomainManagerType` - but no practical example of performing this operation. Maybe you can find someplace else ?

Can anyone recommend me how to create appDomain from assembly that is in ram without performing any loading from hard disk (everything would be kept in ram).

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible because `AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` wants the assembly name and will load it from disk. You said you'd be loading the DLL from disk anyway, why not use the DLL for `AppDomain` stuff as well? Or a more general question, what is the use case here, i.e. why do you need to dynamically load assembly which then in turn creates `AppDomain`? Why not create the `AppDomain` in the calling code?

Comment: I'm analyzing deeper answer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293194/unload-mixed-mode-assembly

Currently I can create unloadable assembly, but I want to get rid of additional C# hosting .dll from disk (Unnecessary clue). It's possible of course to survive without removal of this dll, but I really want to understand alternatives here. 

Why I cannot just load and unload assembly ?!  Why I cannot do it from ram ?